# convert sql query to lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, lambda

How to convert the following sql query to lambda expression?

```
SELECT Username, COUNT(Username) AS Count 
FROM user 
GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: try this:
var grpUsers = empList.GroupBy(user => user.Username) 
    .Select(lst => new {Username = lst.Key, Count = lst.Count()} );

Answer (score 0):

```
 var UserCount = yourEntityObject.GroupBy(m => m.Username)
                       .Select(c => new {Username = c.Key, Count = c.Count()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var grpUsers = empList.GroupBy(user => user.Username)
                         .Select(lst => new {Username = lst.Key, Count = lst.Count()} );
```